# What does it mean that a variable size is language machine implementation dependent?

Tags: c++, c

Hope this is not confusing, but what I mean is why we say for instance that a `long int`'s size in C is machine implementation dépendent.

Does it mean the size is different for ARM processor, x86 processor, or PPC or ...?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it means.

Comment: It means the size *can* be different for different platforms.

Comment: and it can be different for the same platform with different compiler options

Comment: All the above plus ,,, it also means that it can change size with a different version of your compiler on the same platform.

Comment: [Why sizeof built in types except char is compiler dependent in C & C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35517341/995714)

Answer (score 3):

It means that the compiler is free to pick any size that it think is appropriate, within the bounds given. (The `long int` type is defined as having at least a range that corresponds to a 32 bit number.)

Generally it means that different sizes are used for different platforms, depending on the machine word of the processor. Different compilers could even use different sizes for the same platform, and theoretically the same compiler could use different sizes for the same platform in different situations.

Comment: long int is not defined as being at least 32 bits.   The standard only states the minimum range of values a long int is required to represent.    Yes, that works out to at least 32 bits on a binary machine, but the standard does not require a binary machine.   There have been real-world non-binary (e.g. ternary) computing machines, and may well be again - and nothing stopping the construction of an implementation on such machines.

Answer (score 0):

> *"does it mean the size is different for ARM processor , x86 processor , or PPC ..."*

In short: Yes.

Comment: @TheX Well, think about Win32 programs that can still run on Win64 platforms. So it's mereley not only the processor architecture, that makes the difference.

Comment: @TheX :-) "*short*" most probably referrs to the size of the answer!

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ, that's difficult to delineate.  A 32-bit app running on 64-bit architecture is technically running in "emulation" mode for backwards compatibility reasons.

Comment: @alk, does that mean the size of the answer changes for different architecture?

Comment: Most propably yes...!-) @thang