# Why sizeof built in types except char is compiler dependent in C & C++?

Tags: c++, c, types

Why are fundamental types in C and C++ not strictly defined like in Java where an `int` is always 4 bytes and `long` is 8 bytes, etc. To my knowledge in C and C++ only a `char` is defined as 1 byte and everything else is defined differently by different compilers. So an `int` in C and C++ does not have to necessarily be 4 bytes as long as it's longer than a `short` and `short` is longer `char`.
I was just wondering why is that and does it serve any purpose?

Comment: If you think `char` is defined, you haven't read about `CHAR_BIT` yet...

Comment: Are you sure short is longer than char?  i think the guarantee is that it will not be *smaller* than char, much link int will never be *smaller* than long.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Yeah what I meant was greater than or equal. Sorry that was my bad.

Comment: @EOF char is defined as one byte! However, nowhere does it say how many bits one byte has (and historically there were a few systems where one byte was indeed not 8 bits). However, a char is always 1 byte

Comment: @JustSid: A byte is `CHAR_BIT` bit, where `CHAR_BIT >= 8`.

Comment: Off topic: If you want fixed sizes, and the guarantees that come with them, Look [here for C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) and [here for C](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer)

Comment: @EOF: Technically, when OP says that `char` is defined as 1 byte, that is correct, according to the C standard.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: \*sigh\*. It's a comment. If you want me to cite the C11 draft standard, fine: `6.2.5 Types, Section 3 An object declared as type char is large enough to store any member of the basic execution character set.[...]`. The answer to the question is found somewhere in `5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types <limits.h>`. Happy now?

Comment: @EOF: The standard also defines that to be a byte. See 3.6.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Yes, the definitions of `char` and "byte" overlap considerably. That does not mean that one is defined to be the other. Also, I can't for the life of me understand why *this* question, showing no effort or research, is voted so high, and I have to defend my joking comment from so much bikeshedding.

Comment: @EOF: You don't have to defend yourself, because your comment about `CHAR_BIT` is relevant.  Just pointing out that the standard does define `char` to be one byte, just like the OP wrote.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: EOF's comment is obviously about the OP thinking that one `char` equalling one byte means that a `char` is always the same size, range and representation.

Comment: [Exotic architectures the standards committees care about](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6971886/995714), [What platforms have something other than 8-bit char?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2098149/995714)

Comment: @FUZxxl there are 2 languages that are C and C++ and are similar enough respect to this question. Repeating over and over the same dismissing commet without thinking abut it is not useful

Comment: @edc65 They are not similar enough, especially not in subtle details. It's not useful to treat them as equal when discussing nuances of the language's design as the two languages some times have different design in details like this.

Comment: @Ccyan: great question. +1 from me

Comment: Joke answer: so your arrays can be bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` :D

Comment: [Does the size of an int depend on the compiler and/or processor?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2331751/995714), [“C variable type sizes are machine dependent.” Is it really true?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2533319/995714)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The reason is largely because C is portable to a much wider variety of platforms. There are many reasons why the different data types have turned out to be the various sizes they are on various platforms, but at least historically, `int` has been adapted to be the platform's native word size. On the PDP-11 it was 16 bits (and `long` was originally invented for 32-bit numbers), while some embedded platform compilers even have 8-bit `int`s. When 32-bit platforms came around and started having 32-bit `int`s, `short` was invented to represent 16-bit numbers.

Nowadays, most 64-bit architectures use 32-bit `int`s simply to be compatible with the large base of C programs that were originally written for 32-bit platforms, but there have been 64-bit C compilers with 64-bit `int`s as well, not least of which some early Cray platforms.

Also, in the earlier days of computing, floating-point formats and sizes were generally far less standardized (IEEE 754 didn't come around until 1985), which is why `float`s and `double`s are even less well-defined than the integer data types. They generally don't even presume the presence of such peculiarities as infinities, NaNs or signed zeroes.

Furthermore, it should perhaps be said that a `char` is not defined to be 1 byte, but rather to be whatever `sizeof` returns 1 for. Which is not necessarily 8 bits. (For completeness, it should perhaps be added here, also, that "[byte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte)" as a term is not universally defined to be 8 bits; there have been many historical definitions of it, and in the context of the ANSI C standard, a "byte" is actually defined to be the smallest unit of storage that can store a `char`, whatever the nature of `char`.)

There are also such architectures as the 36-bit PDP-10s and 18-bit PDP-7s that have also run C programs. They may be quite rare these days, but do help explain why C data types are not defined in terms of 8-bit units.

Whether this, in the end, really makes the language "more portable" than languages like Java can perhaps be debated, but it would sure be suboptimal to run Java programs on 16-bit processors, and quite weird indeed on 36-bit processors. It is perhaps fair to say that it makes the *language* more portable, but programs written in it less portable.

**EDIT:** In reply to some of the comments, I just want to append, as an opinion piece, that C as a language is unlike languages like Java/Haskell/ADA that are more-or-less "owned" by a corporation or standards body. There is ANSI C, sure, but C is more than ANSI C; it's a living community, and there are many implementations that aren't ANSI-compatible but are "C" nevertheless. Arguing whether implementations that use 8-bit `int`s are C is similar to arguing whether Scots is English in that it's mostly pointless. They use 8-bit `ints` for good reasons, noone who knows C well enough would be unable to reason about programs written for such compilers, and anyone who writes C programs for such architectures would want their `int`s to be 8 bits.

Comment: Your talking about the early days of "floating-point formats" make it sound like everything else was in some vague way standardised!  They weren't and perhaps IEEE 754 *etc* was the first push to standardised basic types.  What about endian-ness?

Comment: @PaulEvans: Sure, but for integers there are at least far fewer degrees of freedom, and non-two's-complement arithmetic for signed integers was weeded out much earlier than floats were standardized. Arguably, floats are hardly even standardized today, with much hardware unable to deal with denormals and other edge cases.

Comment: Well, no.  `short` was not invented to represent 16-bit values on 32-bit platforms.  In fact, `short` and `long` have always been part of C, since early design.  There has also never been a compiler - embedded or not - with an 8-bit `int` (that is one of the historical reasons that the first C standard specified that an `int` should support AT LEAST the range [-32767, 32767] - because there were no implementations that supported a lesser range).

Comment: @Peter: Looking at the source code of the PDP-11/20 C compiler, `short` was not a defined keyword, while `long` was. Also, I have been using at least a PIC C compiler with 8-bit `int`s. You may argue that it wasn't compliant with the standard, but nevertheless, there it was.

Comment: Thanks to the  gods I never had to work on any pre-microcomputer box, but I've heard the war stories.  And those boxes are what C was originally made for.

Comment: I suspect you're looking at modified source of the PDP compiler - the first released version certainly supported `short`.   Yes, there are modified compilers which were non-compliant even with the original designed version of C.   There are plenty of products out there that claim to be C or C++ or <whatever language you choose> compliant, when they are not.   And the same affected early versions of C.

Comment: @Peter: The one I'm looking at is from [DMR's own home page](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/primevalC.html).

Comment: Yeah, but the OP is about *standardised* type, not `short` in general.  And `short` *etc* were *very* weird in the dark ages of computing.  C left it *totally* up to the compiler to decide how to represent it.  And in those dark days there **was no standard** so a C compiler could do *anything*.

Comment: "while some embedded platform compilers even have 8-bit `int`s." - This is blatantly illegal under just about every version of C that has been standardized.  Those compilers cannot be accurately referred to as "C compilers" because they are not to spec.

Comment: @Dolda2000: The standard explicitly defines a `char` to be a single byte, no more, no less. It's just that a byte can be bigger than an *octett* (never smaller). The size of a byte in bits is given by `CHAR_BIT`.

Comment: @Kevin: Under that definition, though, PDP-11 C wasn't C either. There's a good reason why those compilers do use 8-bit `int`s, really. It is the natural thing to do on those platforms. If that means that you can't run your portable ANSI C programs on them, then that's not really a problem, because you probably couldn't anyway.

Comment: @Deduplicator: In that, you're just arguing that definition of the term "byte", and by that point, MACLISP would disagree with you.

Comment: @Dolda2000 Since when does whatever definitions MACLISP uses have any importance when speaking about C? If you don't want to use the term as it's used in C while talking about C, please explicitly call that out (also in your post), or people have to guess what you mean.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I'm not even sure what you're trying to argue. If you are objecting against my use of the word "byte" in the answer, then I simply used it in the way that it was used in the question for the benefit of OP, that is, as an octet. I'm well aware that "byte" doesn't need to mean octet, if that's what you're trying to tell me.

Comment: If you want to do so for the benefit of the OP, at least mark that you are using it as a synonym for an octett instead of a general C byte. Because the OP presumably wants to get the "proper" definitions.

Comment: @Dolda2000: The standard does not explicitly define a byte as 8 bits, so unless you are referring to something else, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Dolda2000: very nice answer. +1

Comment: @PaulEvans, the "box" for which C originally was made was the PDP-11, which had one of the most beautiful and symmetric instruction sets of all time.  I doubt any of your "war stories" concerned the PDP-11.  All of the war stories I ever heard from those days came from IBM, Univac, Honeywell, etc. systems.

Comment: @jameslarge Yes, things like IBM's EBCDIC where alphabetic upper case characters aren't represented by a contiguous set of numbers. Specifically the C that tried to make it easier to port code across these wild beasts. Which C++ inherits from.

Answer (score 23):

The integral data types are not strictly specified so that the compiler can choose whatever is most efficient for the target hardware.  However there are some guarantees on minimum sizes of each type (e.g. `int` is at least 16-bits).

Check out this page: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

Answer (score 10):

Efficiency is part of the answer--for example, if you use C or C++ on a machine that uses 36-bit registers, you don't want to force every operation to include overhead to mask the results so they look/act like 32 bits.

That's really only part of the answer though. The other part is that C and C++ were (and are) intended to be *systems* programming languages. You're intended to be able to write things like virtual machines and operating systems with them.

That means that if (for example) you're writing code that will interact with  the MMU on this 36-bit machine, and you need to set bit 34 of some particular word, the basic intent with C and C++ is that you should be able to do that directly in the language. If the language starts by decreeing that no 36-bit type can exist in the first place, that generally makes it difficult to directly manipulate a 36-bit type in that language.

So, one of the basic premises of C and C++ is that if you need to do something, you should be able to do that something *inside* the language. The corresponding premise in Java was almost exactly the opposite: that what it allowed you to do should be restricted to those operations it could guarantee would be safe and portable to anything.

In particular, keep in mind that when Sun designed Java one of the big targets they had in mind was applets for web pages. They specifically intended to restrict Java to the point that an end-user could run any Java applet, and feel secure in the knowledge that it couldn't possible harm their machine.

Of course, the situation has changed--the security they aimed for has remained elusive, and applets are essentially dead and gone. Nonetheless, most of the restrictions that were intended to support that model remain in place.

I should probably add that this isn't *entirely* an either/or type of situation. There are a number of ways of providing some middle ground. Reasonably recent iterations of both the C and C++ standards include types that `int32_t`. This guarantees a 32-bit, 2's complement representation, just about like a Java type does. So, if you're running on hardware that actually supports a 32-bit two's complement type, `int32_t` will be present and you can use it.

Of course, that's not the only possible way to accomplish roughly the same thing either. Ada, for example, takes a somewhat different route. Instead of the "native" types being oriented toward the machine, and then adding special types with guaranteed properties, it went the other direction, and had native types with guaranteed properties, but also an entire facility for defining a new type that corresponded directly to a target machine. For better or worse, however, Ada has never achieved nearly as wide of usage as C, C++, or Java, and its approach to this particular problem doesn't seem to have been adopted in a lot of other languages either.