# Why are D's integral types fixed instead of unspecified?

Tags: types, size, d, sizeof, fixed-width

I'm accustomed to C and C++ where the majority of fundamental types have unspecified sizes.  I've always thought that these unspecified sizes existed in order to provide efficiency across different architectures.

Yet, after using languages like Rust and D,
I see that all of their fundamental/primitive types are mostly fixed.

Why has D chosen to leave out types of unspecified sizes?
Doesn't this hinder efficiency across machines?
Or are the efficiency concerns far too minuscule to outweigh the  safety of having fixed types?

I was hoping to find some literature on this decision as it was made after two languages that don't have fixed sizes as fundamental types.  Hopefully this isn't too opnion-based.

Comment: The opposite question is over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35517341/why-sizeof-built-in-types-except-char-is-compiler-dependent-in-c-c   I like the quote that "it makes the language more portable, but programs written in the language probably less portable".

Comment: Java too has fixed sizes for types.  It makes it easier to write code at the cost of not necessarily making the code as fast as possible.

Comment: You can use platform specific types if you really want to, for example `size_t` is `uint` on x86 and `ulong` on x86_64 and `real` gives you the highest precision possible in your architecture.

Comment: Most C programs aiming for portability tend to use fixed size aliases anyway...

Answer (score 4):

In the few cases where an integer type's size actually has to be system-specific, those types do not have a fixed size in D - e.g. `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` (because they deal with the size of pointers and how much memory can be addressed). Rather, they're aliases for the appropriate fixed-size type. Similarly, aliases such as `c_long` and `c_long_double` exist for interacting with C code. Those need to have variable sizes based on the platform that they're on, whereas for stuff like `int` or `long`, D could have gone either way, but it chose to do what other, modern languages such as Java and C# did and went with fixed sizes.

Arguably, fixed sizes actually *improve* portability. If you write code that operates specifically on a 32-bit integer rather than an integer of unknown size, then you get consistent behavior across all platforms. This is particularly critical when dealing with stuff like bitwise operations, but it can reduce problems with code in general. You're not going to suddenly get problems with overflow just because you compiled your program on a new platform that had a smaller integer size. You're not going to have to go over every line of your program to make sure that the integer sizes on a new platform will work properly with the code. With a fixed integer size, you know that any bugs related to integer sizes changing when changing platforms won't happen. So, your code is portable in a way that code that uses variable sized integers isn't.

And in D code, `size_t` sometimes causes problems for programmers precisely because it's size is platform-dependent. Code that compiles on a 64-bit platform won't compile on a 32-bit platform if it does stuff like assign a `long` to a `size_t`, and code that compiles on a 32-bit platform won't compile on a 64-bit platform if it does stuff like assign `size_t` to an `int`. C/C++ has fewer of those problems, because unlike D, it doesn't give an error an narrowing conversions, but going the C/C++ route and not making those errors would mean that it would be harder to catch bugs related to narrowing conversions. If D used platform-dependent sizes in general, then any compiler checks for narrowing conversions would run a very high risk of causing errors on some platforms but not others, and you'd risk bugs in relation to changes in integer sizes (e.g. overflow) on some platforms but not others. Making the integer sizes consistent makes the code consistent across platforms.

In the past, it was indeed the case on a number of architectures that using the "word size" of the machine was more efficient, but with today's architectures, the situation is far more complicated than that. x86_64 machines operate on 32-bit integers very efficiently to the point that it's pretty questionable that 64-bit integers will be more efficient in general, and the fact that 32-bit integers use less memory makes it more likely that variables will stay within the CPU cache lines (as well as simply having less memory that has to be copied), so they *can* be more efficient than 64-bit integers. But it depends on the code, the exact CPU, and the actual workload. It's my understanding that modern x86 CPUs essentially emulate x86 but are really way more complicated than that underneath the hood (e.g. they have way more registers in reality than the x86 microcode has to play with), and they do all kinds of crazy stuff that machines didn't do 20 or 30 years ago in order to optimize what's being run. So, the situation is *way* more complicated than it once was, and expecting to get a performance boost specifically because your integer size matches the word size for the machine is a huge oversimplification. Profiling is required to figure out what's going to work best for a particular application, and it's often the complete opposite of what you expect. So, it's not necessarily a gain to try and match your integer sizes to the word size of the machine, and it makes your code more error prone.

Personally, it's been my practice in C++ for years now to only use `int` when dealing with integers that I know are going to be relatively small and won't have any bitwise operations done on them. Otherwise, I use types like `int32_t` and `int64_t`, and I never use types like `long` or `short`, because once you need to start using different integer types to get a particular size of integer, it's just less error-prone to use fixed-sized integers than to use a type that will be within a certain range. And there are plenty of other folks out there that do the same thing. Without doing that, if you have to take a 32-bit program and port it to 64-bits, you're going to be praying like crazy that you don't run into all kinds of weird, hard-to-track-down bugs caused by the change in integer sizes, whereas if you've used fixed-size integer everywhere, you have none of those concerns.

Using variable-sized integer types is just begging for bugs which are platform-specific, and it's often questionable that it will improve performance. At this point, variable-sized integers seem to be a C-ism that most languages that came after did not adopt. From what I've seen, most either have predominantly fixed sized integer types, or they have the equivalent to `BigInt` and divorce themselves from the hardware integers completely. And as D is a systems language, it went with fixed-size integers rather than making the built-in integer type act like a `BigInt`.