# Is c sizeof() function dependent on the host computer?

Tags: c, cross-compiling, sizeof

Is the sizeof() function dependent on the host computer. If you were to use sizeof(structure) and get a return of 4 bytes in a Linux computer will that result changes if you were to compile the program in a different operating system?

Would cross compiling fix this issues? Say if you were expecting 4 bytes if you compile On a Linux and instead of moving it to a different operating system, you cross compiler it on your and than move it to the other operating system. Wouldn’t the package size be the same at that point?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why sizeof built in types except char is compiler dependent in C & C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35517341/why-sizeof-built-in-types-except-char-is-compiler-dependent-in-c-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes for sure the size of the structure can change depending on the operating system
that's one of the main reasons to use sizeof() to make sure you get the same functionality on different operating systems.

Comment: The hardware and operating system influence the choice, but the ultimate determination is made by the C implementation. One might design a C implementation to support software written for some old system while running on new hardware, and its structures would reflect the design of the old system, not the current system.